# OpenAI GPT-3 API error: "Cannot specify both model and engine"

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, openai-api, gpt-3

So I'm working on some python code that works with chatgpt3. What it does is it sends a request with a prompt and then gets the reply, but I keep getting Errors. The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(response_json['choices'][0]['text'])
KeyError: 'choices'
```

Here is my code:

```
import json
import requests
import os
data = {
    "prompt": "What is the meaning of life?",
    "model": "text-davinci-002"
}

response = requests.post("https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci/completions", json=data, headers={
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {apikey}",
})

response_json = json.loads(response.text)

print(response_json['choices'][0]['text'])
```

I do have an API key that is valid and the JSON code I don't get the JSON code.

```
{'error': {'message': 'Cannot specify both model and engine', 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': None}}
```

I have tried different API keys and that didn't work. i even looked up all the different models for chatgpt and it still doesn't work

Comment: The error is crystal clear - you can't specify both a model and an engine. So, remove one of them. `model` is a good choice to start.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. What is the source of the code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All [Engines API endpoints](https://platform.openai.com/docs/deprecations/2022-06-03-legacy-endpoints) are deprecated.

[image: Screenshot]

Change the URL from this...

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci/completions
```

...to this.

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/completions
```

If you run `test.py` the OpenAI API will return a completion. You'll get a different completion because the `temperature` parameter is not set to `0`. I got the following completion:

> The meaning of life is to find out and fulfil the purpose and meaning...

**test.py**

```
import json
import requests
import os

data = {
    "prompt": "What is the meaning of life?",
    "model": "text-davinci-003"
}

response = requests.post("https://api.openai.com/v1/completions", json=data, headers={
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {apikey}"
})

response_json = json.loads(response.text)

print(response_json["choices"][0]["text"])
```

Comment: It might be worthy to mention that the Engines end-point is deprecated. Ref. https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/engines

Answer (score -1):

```
import json
import requests
import os

data = {
    "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    "messages": [{"role": "user", "content": "c++ program hello world"}],
    "temperature": 0.7
}

response = requests.post("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", json=data, headers={
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {YOURAPIKEY}"
})

response_json = json.loads(response.text)

print(response_json)
```

USE THIS URL  = https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).