# How do I make an API call to GPT-3 correctly?

Tags: python, python-requests, gpt-3

I am trying to make an API call to GPT-3 but I am getting an error (Bad request 400). Here is my code:

```
url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/gpt-3/jobs"

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "sk-apikey"
}

data = {
    "model": "text-davinci-002",
    "prompt": "Correct this to standard English : Who are you",
    "max_tokens": 60        
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI API error: "Cannot specify both model and engine"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75176667/openai-api-error-cannot-specify-both-model-and-engine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the url and fixing the Authorization header...

```
url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/completions"

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}"
}

data = {
    "model": "text-davinci-002",
    "prompt": "Correct this to standard English : Who are you \n",
    "max_tokens": 60        
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
response.json()
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. The URL needed to be changed.